# How to set UIPickerView as inputView to UITextField in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uipickerview

I am trying to open `UIPickerView` as inputView to `UITextfield`.

Here is my code in `textFieldDidBeginEditing`:

```
  UIPickerView *categoryPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 43, 320, 480)];
    categoryPicker.delegate = self;
    categoryPicker.dataSource = self;
    [categoryPicker  setShowsSelectionIndicator:YES];
    txtCategory.inputView =  categoryPicker;

  UIToolbar *_providerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 56)];
    _providerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    [_providerToolbar sizeToFit];

    NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
    [barItems addObject:flexSpace];

    UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismissActionSheet)];

    [barItems addObject:doneBtn];

    [_providerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];
    txtCategory.inputAccessoryView = _providerToolbar;
```

It's working fine for first time, but when I am selecting any value from `UIPickerView` it's hiding and my `UITextfield` is editable and UIPickerView is not showing at that time. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I wouldn't put that code in `textFieldDidBeginEditing:`, that method is called after the `UITextField` has already became first responder and could be what is causing your issue. Try moving this code to `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to move your code to `viewDidLoad:`. Because `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` is called when textField loads the keyboard for it. So It is not the right time to change the `inputAccessoryView` of the textField.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this...

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd MMM, yyyy"];

    UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];

    [datePicker setMaximumDate:now];

    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;

    txtForDate.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate:datePicker.date];

    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateTextField:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [txtForDate setInputView:datePicker];
```

// txtForDate is UITextField